# Cannot find PHPUnit in include path

Tags: wamp, phpstorm

I decided to install PhpStorm but I couldn't make it start a very basic PHP project (Hello world).

I get this error all the time:

> Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.;D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear)

I even installed PEAR, though I have no clue why I would need it.

Comment: Your PHP (**Yes, PHP itself**) cannot find PHPUnit files -- you need to make sure that it can find it (edit `include_path` setting in your php.ini). **Alternatively:** use PHPUnit via Composer or as PHAR archive -- PhpStorm v6 supports PHPUnit used this way: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHPUnit+Installation+via+Composer+in+PhpStorm

Comment: That's, of course, if you are trying to execute actual **PHPUnit tests**. If you are **NOT** intended to do this (it's not 100% clear for me, unfortunately -- but I believe it's the case) -- then you are doing something wrong (most likely: using entry of **wrong** Run/Debug Configuration type). If so -- create entry of correct type and use it instead (`Run | Edit Configurations...`)

Comment: Where normally those PHPUnit files are located?

Comment: **The question is:** are you trying to execute PHPUnit tests or not? Maybe you do not need them at all. **In any case:** they are located where you have installed/downloaded them -- I'm not using WAMP myself and cannot give you exact location, but if you installed PHPUnit via PEAR, then check pear location. Or **just do a global search** for "PHPUnit" -- the best option as requires no guessing.

Comment: I'm trying to run the project without any tests.

Comment: Then you do not need PHPUnit at all. As mentioned in my 2nd comment -- use **correct** Run/Debug configuration -- you can edit/create it via `Run | Edit Configurations...` -- use `+` (plus) icon to add new one. You can then select active one on main toolbar (drop-down box next to Run/Debug buttons)

Comment: Okay I did that now I face a bigger problem :( Process finished with exit code -1073741819

Comment: Check your PHP error log for details. Possibly missing some extension or something. Plus .. this site is not good for such problem solving. maybe use JetBrain's forums instead (where you can provide pics and other details): http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/wi?view=discussions . So far I think it's a PHP misconfiguration